# jquery.validation .netCore 6

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I created a new .NET 6 project. And I put the following code in the Index.

```
<form>
<input type="text" asp-for="Name" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js" ></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" >
</script>
```

The C # codes are as follows:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public void OnGet()
    {
        
    }
    public void OnPost(string Name)
    {
        
    }
}
```

When I run the project in the browser:

```
<main b-g6ltozs93r="" role="main" class="pb-3">
        <form novalidate="novalidate">
<input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Name" name="Name" value="">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
</main>
```

I had not Required the name field .
How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nullable element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts) configures how the compiler interprets the nullability of types and what warnings are emitted. `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` means `Non-nullable unless declared with ?`.Here are two solutions:

1.Try to remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in .csproj file.

[image]

2.Add `?` to `Name`:

```
public string? Name { get; set; }
```

Then you will not have `data-val-required="The Name field is required."` in your html code.